# How to prove this equality among differential operators involving chain rule?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, chain-rule, differential-operators

Given the PDE
$$a_{11} u_{x x}+2 a_{12} u_{x y}+a_{22} u_{y y}+a_{1} 
u_{x}+a_{2} u_{y}+a_{0} u=0$$
where
$$\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y\\
\end{bmatrix}
=\left(\begin{array}{rr}
\cos\left(t\right) & -\sin\left(t\right) \\
\sin\left(t\right) & \cos\left(t\right)
\end{array}\right) \begin{bmatrix} x' \\ y' \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} \cos(t)  & \sin(t) \\ -\sin(t) & \cos(t) \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
x\\ y
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} x'\\ y' \end{bmatrix}$$

---

How does one deduce that

$\begin{aligned} \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}} &=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right) \\ &=\left(\frac{\partial x^{\prime}}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\prime}}+\frac{\partial y^{\prime}}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial y^{\prime}}\right)\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right) \end{aligned}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $x'=x\cos(t)+y\sin(t)$ and $y'=-x\sin(t)+y\cos(t)$ then by the chain rule

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x'}+\frac{\partial y'}{\partial x}\frac{\partial }{\partial y'}=\cos(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial x'}-\sin(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial y'}$$